# How to check if Dataproc cluster in error state is due to network issue

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc

When creating my cluster, I see this errors in the logs

```
Only 0 out of 2 minimum required datanodes running. 

2021-07-16T02:41:57.264Z Starting scan to move intermediate done files
```

Answer (score 3):

Please check if your firewall rule is properly configured.
Please check here for more information.

- [Dataproc clusters firewall rule requirement](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/network#firewall_rule_requirement)
- [Creating Dataproc Cluster with Custom VPC](https://github.com/gbadebo/Dataproc_Tutorial/blob/main/Dataproc_network_1.md)
- [Creating a Dataproc cluster: considerations, gotchas & resources](https://medium.com/google-cloud/creating-a-dataproc-cluster-considerations-gotchas-resources-930294ddb7f3)